# How to like facebook messages

Tags: android

In my application I have one expandable list view which displays Facebook messages.

When a user clicks the list view then a child view opens in that I have a button called Like. By clicking the Like button the original message should be liked in Facebook

One important thing is that it should not ask login details from the user. I searched a lot on the web but I find any good tutorial.

I don't have any basic idea of Facebook. Please provide me with some suggestions of how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: How would they like something without being logged in?

Comment: me too confused on this,please clear my problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to like Facebook messages, you need to ask a permission for that with the Facebook SDK :

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

So Basically, you can do SSO with Facebook SDK, he will just ask for the permission needed if the user is already logged on his Facebook application.

Take a look at the sample on the Android SDK Facebook on the link above.

When you have the "like" permission (`publish_stream`), you can do it like that :

```
Request likeFacebook = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), fBPostId + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // analyse your response
         }
});
Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeFacebook);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,it will ask login credentials or not,in my case it should not ask login credentials,i am little bit confused how to like something without asking credentials from the user,can you please clear my problem

Comment: It will not ask for credentials if you are logged with your Facebook app. But you need to ask the permission publish_stream for your app, so the user will be ask one time to allor your app.